# Appending a javascript variable to an HTML property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple tables which are output via a php function. The tables are then to be formatted with the DataTables plugin, which requires me to reference the table ID's after the document is ready:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
   for (i = 0; i < ntables; i++) { 
       $('#Main_Data_Table'+i).DataTable();
   }
} );
```

So when I'm creating the tables I simply want to append the table number (ntables) to the id kind of like the following:

```
<script>ntables++;</script>
<table id="Main_Data_Table<script>echo ntables</script>" class="display">
```

I'm used to using PHP, hence the echo which of course doesn't work. How do I simply append the ntables variable to the ID when I'm creating the tables?

Comment: In your php is your table creation in a for loop? If so could you include that in your question?

Comment: You can save the need for ugly incremental `id` attributes and looping over them by using a single common class on all the tables, and then using that class to initialise all the datatables in a single line: `$('.datatable').DataTable();`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create HTML elements with dynamic IDs, you need to do use a loop in a programming language. You can use a server-side script to create the HTML, or build all the tables in Javascript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ntables; i++) {
    $("#container").append($("<table>", { 
        id: "Main_Data_Table_" + i,
        "class": "display"
    }).DataTable());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JS way

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    var tables = $("table.display");

    for(i = 1; i <= tables.length; i++){
      $(tables[i]).attr("id", "Main_Data_Table"+i);
    }    

} );
```

So in your php code you would just need to generate a bunch of tables with `class="display"`

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to add id directly from PHP when you are printing tables. If, for some reason, this is not possible, then you could try .getElementsByClassName("some class") then change each element id.